# Java - Why can't I change a variable in a while loop?

Tags: java

For some reason, whenever I do this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean c = true;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 10) {
            System.out.println(c);
            c = false;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

This prints `true` every single time.

EDIT:
I ran it a couple of times, than the 5th time it worked! I am confused. I think I was building it wrong... I guess.

Comment: Your JVM must be different from mine! Seriously: Your output does not make logical sense, and so one of your assumptions must be wrong.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels ???

Comment: Make sure you are recompiling and running the latest version of your code.

Comment: did you try stepping through it with a debugger?

Comment: It is printing true once and hten false rest of the times

Comment: @SusanYanders how are you compiling/building/executing this code?

Comment: Can you posted your whole method here?

Answer (score 4):

You must be compiling / building it wrong. My output:

```
true
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
```

...exactly as expected. (This is with the latest Oracle JDK, though I can't imagine any other JVM would behave differently - it would certainly be very broken if it did.)